# VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' Object required:

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm completely new to VB and have run into what I imagine must be a common error for noobs.
I'm trying to split a string into an array with this snippet:

```
Dim myString, myArray
myString = "split-this"
myArray = myString.Split("-")
```

This gives me the error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'
Object required: 'split-this'
```

Could someone kindly tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
myArray = Split(myString, "-")
```

Comment: +1 Because String is not an object in VBS thus has no propery/method implementation

Comment: +1 and thank you; had a feeling I was doing something daft. :)