# Error 800a01a8 Object Required for String

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Why does this string need to be declared as an object when comparing to Nothing?

```
Dim BlankStr
BlankStr = "blank"
If BlankStr Is Nothing Then
End If
```

I also cannot compare `If 1 Is 1 Then`. Why can't I compare primitives?

Comment: are you asking why a variable has to be declared at all?

Comment: I'm asking why BlankStr can't be compared to Nothing in this instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBScript has data (sub) [types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). Besides simple (sub) types like Strings:

```
>> x = "blank"
>> WScript.Echo VarType(x), TypeName(x)
>>
8 String
```

there are Objects:

```
>> Set y = New RegExp
>> WScript.Echo VarType(y), TypeName(y)
>>
9 IRegExp2
```

To assign an object to a variable, you need [Set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), to compare objects, you need [Is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hck4s70%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). Simple (non-object) values have their own comparison operator.

To compare a string against another:

```
>> WScript.Echo CStr(x = "blank"), CStr(x = "object")
>>
True False
```

Trying to use a simple value 'as if it were an object', throws an "object required" error:

```
>> Set z = "blank"
>>
Error Number:       424
Error Description:  Object required
>> WScript.Echo CStr(x Is x)
>>
Error Number:       424
Error Description:  Object required
```

Read [A Whole Lot Of Nothing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/30/a-whole-lot-of-nothing/).

Comment: Gotcha, so `=` is a different operator than `is`.

Answer (score 1):

String is not an object in VBScript.

So if you compare any primitive data types, you just use `=` to compare if they are equal. If does not require objects.

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/vbscript_ref_functions.asp

Answer (score 0):

According [a comment to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21934797/23528), VBScript doesn't have a string type. Instead it sounds like strings are primitives. `Is` works with object references.

Comment: If the BlankStr is a primitive, then why does it also error out when I compare `If BlankStr Is "blank" Then`. Do If statements require objects?